# How many 5+ letter words can you find?

Tags: word, no-computers, letters, crosswords

NYT does a word hive in every Sunday edition, and I quite enjoy it, so I decided to make my own, using the same rules. Check it out:
[image: n-o-l-u-y-r-S]

If you're unfamiliar, here are the rules.

- You may only use the letters in the hive to create your words, and you must use the center letter "S" in each qualifying word.
- Words must be 5+ letters long. And they can't be proper names, non-English words, etc. Rule of thumb, if it's not in the OxEn dictionary, it doesn't count.
- There's at least one word, which uses all the letters – that word is worth 2 points
- Every other word (that doesn't use all the letters) is worth 1 point
  •
  •
  •
- Hint: you can reuse letters, as long as they're in the hive

*I created the hive, so obviously have an advantage, but I found 17 points worth of words, and friends/family gave me 2 more words, for a total of 19. Can you beat my score?*

Comment: Just to make sure, the position of the letters in the hive (adjacent or not) does not impose a restriction on the order of the letters in the word, does it?

Comment: You might want to add a no-computers tags to this question, because boy is it tempting to write a script for this

Comment: Thank you for the "no computers" note @VotBear. That's amazingly cool though. Wish I had those skills. And no, the position of the letters doesn't matter, except for the center letter, which is special, and which you must use in every qualifying word, as mentioned.

Comment: @BeechwoodReview  Oh sorry, I was wrong.  I just want to say, that no-computer tag can not be placed in this kind of puzzle.

Comment: huh – why can't that tag be places in this kind of puzzle? @JamalSenjaya it's possible, even reasonable to assume that humans have enough knowledge to find a bunch of words. I'm somewhat new here, so let me know! Thanks.

Comment: @BeechwoodReview Because people keep cheating, and no body know.

Comment: hmmm...seems only a snool would do such a thing @JamalSenjaya. Anyway, I didn't even know a script was possible and got 17. Meager compared to some others, but I guess it's up to the individual to decide if they wanna challenge themselves or na...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71805/discussion-between-beechwood-review-and-jamal-senjaya).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the running list, including the two community submitted answers so far, which have added more words to the total. Hats off to Herb Wolfe! wowza

> lolls
> loons
> lossy
> lours
> lousy
> lulls
> noons
> nouns
> nulls
> nylons
> rolls
> slurry
> slurs
> slyly
> snool
> solos
> sonly
> sonny
> sonorous
> sonorously
> sorry
> souls
> sourly
> sours
> sully
> sunny
> surly
> unrolls
> yours
> yoyos (?)

Comment: Maybe this should be community wiki? I'm pretty sure there's an option in edit for that.

Comment: what about `lorry`?

Answer (score 2):

I've come up with 21, including the 2 point answer.

In alphabetical order:

> lolls
>  loons
>  lossy
>  lousy
>  lulls
>  nulls
>  rolls
>  slurs
>  slurry
>  sonny
>  sonorous
>  sonorously
>  sorry
>  souls
>  sours
>  sully
>  sunny
>  surly
>  unrolls

Comment: Wow! Impressive. Also: lours (variant spelling), shyly, slyly, sonly, sourly, yours.

Comment: @BeechwoodReview there's no 'h', so shyly isn't possible.

Comment: true! stupid me

Comment: Change it to 'slyly' ...er.. oops you have it already

Answer (score 2):

I found

> 16 so far.

Words:

> LOUSY
>  LOSSY
>  LULLS
>  NOUNS
>  NOONS
>  NYLONS
>  ROLLS
>  SLURRY
>  SLURS
>  SOURS
>  SOULS
>  SORRY
>  SUNNY
>  UNROLLS
>  YOURS
>  YOYOS (?)

Comment: Awesome job in quick time. Also just found another one. "Solos". So we're at 31 total points.